# How to dispatch multiple actions in react redux using useDispatch()

Tags: redux, dispatch

I know that there are a lot of similar questions but I couldn't find how to dispatch multiple actions.

I have a button. On click I call the function *modalOpen* which should dispatch two actions - open Modal and send api request.

```
const modalOpen = async (type) => {      
     const dispatch = useDispatch();      
    dispatch({ type: "openModal", payload: true });
    dispatch({ type: "getActivity", payload: getNewActivity });
  };
```

Comment: Have you looked into `extraReducers`?

Comment: That example should work exactly as written, with the exception that the `const dispatch = useDispatch()` has to happen at the top level of the component and not _inside_ the callback function.